# How to export properties of objects in a list to CSV efficiently in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, export-to-csv

Basically i do have a database import/export file that i needed to edit (file is 1.4m lines). The editing is quite fast even though i have to go through all the lines and check if 2 fields are correct length and if not just fulfill it to the correct length.

The problem i am having is the export into csv file being really ineffective.

I am currently using a Method i created that basically creates a string and then creates a new line with every object from list (as seen in the code below). The problem is that it goes really slowly. I guess it is pretty slow because all the objects that are in the list have 14 parameters that are being put into the string (code is edited so it is not that long). But is there any way to make that faster?

```
public static string CsvExport(List<DataLine> inputList)
        {
            string exportString = "";
            string delimiter = ";";

            foreach (DataLine line in inputList)
            {
                exportString += line.SCREENINGREQUESTUNIQUEID + delimiter + line.REQUESTTIMESTAMP + "\n";
            }

            return exportString;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First. Use right tool for the job - [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netframework-4.8)

```
var exportString = lines
    .Aggregate(
        new StringBuilder(), 
        (builder, line) => 
        {
            builder.Append(line.SCREENINGREQUESTUNIQUEID);
            builder.Append(";"); 
            builder.AppendLine(line.REQUESTTIMESTAMP);

            return builder;
        })
    .ToString();
```

Notice that string concatenation with `+` operator will instantiate new instance of string every time `+` is used, where previous string instance will still remain in the memory (for 1M lines this will become important). With `StringBuilder` you can do this efficiently without instantiating new objects and use exact amount of memory you need for the whole file without copying previous values as Thomas mentions in his answer.

Second. If you writing text to the file, you can do this in more memory efficient way by using [StreamWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-write-text-to-a-file) (but probably not speed efficient)

```
using (var csv = new StreamWriter("pathToFile"))
{
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        csv.Write(line.SCREENINGREQUESTUNIQUEID);
        csv.Write(";"); 
        csv.WriteLine(line.REQUESTTIMESTAMP);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You say that you need to export to a CSV file, but actually, you're exporting to a string in RAM.

Using `+=` on a string like you do will create at least 1.4 million temporary strings, which will all need to be garbage collected. If each line is 100 characters long, you'll have a memory throughput of

```
200 + 400 + 600 + ...
```

with 1.4 million terms. That is 200 * sum(1..1.4M) or ~ 200 TB. At a rate of DDR3 1333 = 10.6 GB/s, this will take about 20000 seconds or 5:30 hours

Write to the file using a [StreamWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=netframework-4.8). This will save you tons of memory in RAM, reduce the memory and be faster, since writing to disk can already occur while you're still computing.